# All drivers software for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, drivers, bluetooth, soundcard, gpu-driver

Is there any utility app or software to detect and update drivers for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, such for graphics card, sound card, wireless and bluetooth drivers, USB drivers, System management drivers, other hardware support and etc? This is role prevent crashes and keep stable and improve graphic performance if use latest version, especially for gaming 3D experience, watching HD or 3D movies, etc. I'm searching in internet, but I'm cannot find any solution at all in one-click solution. Like example:

- For Windows like example Driver Booster 2 from IObit: http://www.iobit.com/driver-booster.php
- For Linux ???

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've installed drivers manually from third-party websites, all of your system drivers should be updated automatically by Ubuntu's built-in "Software Updater".  This is one of the great things about Ubuntu and other operating systems that use package management (Ubuntu uses the `apt` program for this).  Anything installed via `apt`, Ubuntu Software Center, or from a PPA should update automatically.  Everything that the Ubuntu installer put on your computer during installation of Ubuntu should also update automatically, including drivers.

If you've installed anything using the "Additional Drivers" utility, these should also update, although only if the third-party publisher (e.g. nVidia) updates them.  In some cases you may have to manually select a newer version using the same utility.

So if all you're worried about is keeping drivers up-to-date, then worry no more.  Unlike in Windows, Ubuntu keeps all your drivers up-to-date for you via the same utility that updates everything else.

Just one quick note about Ubuntu's release schedule; most releases are only supported for 9 months after initial release.  However, in your case you have an LTS (Long Term Support) release, so yours will be supported for 5 years after initial release (until April 2019).  Once the 9 months or 5 years run out, the version becomes EOL (End of Life) and no longer receives updates. See [this wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for release support information.